# How to prevent native browser default pinch to zoom behavior?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser, zooming, pinchzoom

This question has been asked in a couple different flavors, but none satisfy.

The native browser (Google Chrome for Mac, for instance) supports the "pinch to zoom" gesture by default which will zoom the whole viewport. How do I disable (react to) this default behavior so I can write my own pinching/zooming logic? Google Maps https://maps.google.com/ seems to have achieved this since pinching on the map will only scale the map area, leaving the rest of the UI intact, while pinching on the left sidebar shows the default behavior.

I have tried a few approaches such as HTML `"viewport"` meta tag, CSS `touch-action: none;` and JavaScript `document.addEventListener('touchmove', e => { e.preventDefault() })`, but they all seem to only work on mobile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I accidentally found a solution which works on Chrome. You basically have to `preventDefault` the `"wheel"` event. `ctrlKey` will be `true` if it is a pinch event instead of a scroll.

```
element.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
   const { ctrlKey } = event
   if (ctrlKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return
   }
}, { passive: false })
```

I'd guess this is how Google Maps does it.

The (most) cross-browser solution is probably a combination of the techniques mentioned: `user-scalable=no` in the `"viewport"` meta tag for the browsers that do support it and this one for native Chrome.

Comment: it works but I got this error in the console. `[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>`

Comment: You can't invoke `preventDefault` on a passive event listener @KendoJaa. To do that, you would have to remove the `{ passive: true }` from your listener, wherever it's being set. Check out [EventListenerOptions](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use this meta tag:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in the question, the "viewport" meta tag will only prevent the default pinch to zoom behavior on (some) mobile browsers.

Comment: Which Browsers doesn't it work on? You'll want `*{ box-sizing:border-box } html,body{ width:100%; height:100% }`.

Comment: Native browsers such as Chrome (on macOS) and Safari ignore the `user-scalable=no` portion of the `"viewport"` meta tag.

Comment: Well there you have it. You cannot control what a Browser vendor lets the Client do.

Comment: Right, but since Google Maps is able to do that, we mortals shall be too!

Comment: Are you using a regular Browser when accessing Google Maps on an iPhone? I have an Android. Can't say I didn't try.